# Why is Java saying these types are incompatible?

Tags: java, java-8

Here is my code:

```
private BiFunction<B,
        BiFunction<B, ? extends Object, B>,
        Function<? extends Object, B>>
        applyPartial = (b, m) -> (v) -> m.apply(b, v);
```

Java says:

> File.java:[92,141] incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object

Column 141 is the **`v`**  in `m.apply(b, v)`.

Why won't this compile?

Comment: I don't know—I guessed it was *v*. Is a capture the same thing as an enclosed variable?

Comment: it seems to me you are getting an instance of Object, which you are trying to cast to another type. Every instance of that other type (which is a subclass of Object) will be an instance of Object, but that doesn't mean that every instance of Object is an instance (and can be casted to) the subclass.

Comment: Yeah—I don't see where `Object` is involved here. I don't have that anywhere. only `? extends Object`.

Comment: What was your intention with `? extends Object`?  Do you care what type that is?

Comment: It can be any type, so I interpreted that as `? extends Object`. But it's not great, because I have casting upstream from this.

Answer (score 3):

You have to name the type that you want in place of the wildcard capture in this case.  Java isn't able to ensure that both capture conversions are equivalent.

Since you can't create a generic type on a function call, you should create a factory function to create the function instead:

```
// Provided B is supplied as a class type
public <C> BiFunction<B, BiFunction<B, C, B>, Function<C, B>> createCurrier() {
    return (b, m) -> v -> m.apply(b, v);
}
```

```
// B is an explicit type parameter
public <B, C> BiFunction<B, BiFunction<B, C, B>, Function<C, B>> createCurrier() {
    return (b, m) -> v -> m.apply(b, v);
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I am re-working my program now to avoid the `? extends Object`. I think I've got a design flaw I can fix.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different occurrences of `? extends Object`, and there is no way for the compiler to ensure that they are the same. You need to name it to make sure that you have the same type in both places:

```
private BiFunction<B, BiFunction<B, C, B>, Function<C, B>> applyPartial =
   (b, m) -> (v) -> m.apply(b, v);
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain the errors wording?

Comment: Also, could you please suggest a better title to my question? Or just edit it to be better.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure why the message says `capture#1 of ? extends Object` in one place, but `Object` in the other. A guess is that the compiler can't determine a working type for the last lambda expression, and defaults back to `Object`.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation on how I can give a name to `? extends Object`?

Comment: In the code in the answer I have given the name `C` to it for example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean a syntatic mechanism by which I can create `C`

Comment: @Keppil: that behavior is according to the specification. For the (outer) lambda expression, it will infer `Function<Object, B>` as return type, which is compatible with target type’s return type `Function<? extends Object, B>`. Then it detects that that function can’t pass `Object` to the second parameter of that `BiFunction` which is `? extends Object`. This is in line with the behavior in non-lambda scenarios, an instance of type `? extends Object` is guaranteed to be `Object` (maybe a subclass) and can’t be passed to something expecting an unknown type `? extends Object`…